# Integral domain of the form $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}] $.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Considering an integral domain of the form : $$ Z[\sqrt{d}] = \{a + b \sqrt{d}\:\: |\:\:a,b,d \in Z \}$$

Also , $d \neq 1$ and $d$ is not divisible by the square of a prime number.

We define a function $N$ as follows : $N(a + b \sqrt{d}) = |a^{2} - db^{2}|$.

We need to show that $N(x) = 0$ iff $x=0$ , where $x\in Z[\sqrt{d}]$.

Let us first say that $N(x)=0$ , => $N(a + b\sqrt{d})=0$ , => $|a^{2} - db^{2}|=0$ ,

=> $(a^{2} - db^{2})=0$ , => $(a + b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d})=0$.

Now somehow we need to prove that $(a+b\sqrt{d})=0$.

If we let $(a-b\sqrt{d})=0$ , then , $\dfrac{a}{b} = \sqrt{d}$. Now the term in L.H.S is rational whereas the term in R.H.S can be an irrational too. ( if we take d=2). Hence this is not possible.

But similarly can't we prove that $(a + b \sqrt{d}) \neq 0$ too ?

Am I doing something wrong ? Kindly help !

Comment: So you can prove that $N(X) \neq 0$ for all $x$... Continue the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your doubt, perhaps directly:

$$N(x)=0\implies a^2-b^2d=0\implies a^2=b^2d\stackrel{b\neq0}\implies$$

$$d=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\implies \sqrt d=\pm\frac ab\in\Bbb Q\rightarrow\text{ contradiction},\;\text{so then it must be}$$

$$b=0\implies a^2=0\iff a=0\implies a+b\sqrt d=0$$

and we're done.

The other direction is trivial

Comment: I fixed what I believe was a small typo (you had written $d=\frac ab\in \Bbb Q$). Also, note that within double dollars, a double backslash gives a line break. For instance ``$$x+y=z\\x=z-y$$`` becomes $$x+y=z\\x=z-y$$

Comment: @Arthur Thank you very much, both for the typo correction and for the tip. It can become handy.

Comment: Sir, contradiction to what? Further isn't $√d$ may possibly belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$ for example when $a^2=2b^2$?